# Manually call a cron task Symfony 1.4

Tags: cron, symfony-1.4

I have a cron task placed under myProject/lib/task. This cron works daily for over a year.

However now I have to create a button inside my project to do the same process as the cron whenever my client needs. The code is too complex and I can't rewrite everything on a normal action.

Is there a way to call a cron task from a normal action?

Comment: Are you sure it's a cron trask? I think it's a symfony task executed by cron at certain times. What's the purpose of the task? It's a long running heavy weight task with high cpu and/or memory usage or lightweight one? If it's lightweight you should refactor it's code to be reusable in an action. You don't have to rewrite it from scratch.

Comment: I'm doing my best to comunicate in english, but a Symfony task executed by cron and a cron task sounds the same to me. This task connects on a external webservice and updates a table and it is complex because the webservice is poorly documented, and their functions has nom-friendly names, so nobody in my team really remembers/understands how this code works since it was write a year ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can call a task from an action, you just need to add a link to it and you'll be good. I've used the standard Symfony 'Clear Cache' task in the example, but you can change it to yours:

```
public function executeRunTaskTest(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  // need to be working in the project root
  chdir(sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir'));

  // init the task we want to run
  $task = new sfCacheClearTask($this->dispatcher, new sfFormatter());

  // run the task
  $task->run(
    array(), // array of arguments
    array(
      'app' => 'frontend',
      'env' => 'prod',
      'type' => 'all',
    ) // array of options
  );

  // back to where we came from
  $this->redirect($request->getReferer());
}
```

You could also use the PHP `exec()` or `shell_exec()` functions, but this Symfony solution is probably easier. :)

Comment: Thanks. It needs more tests but this is exactly what I was looking for.